# Append a div to a link in nested list using jquery

Tags: jquery, list, append

I'm using a list like this

```
<ul class="menu"> 
<li><a>Test Page</a></li>
<li><a>Test Page</a></li>
<li><a>Test Page</a>
    <ul>
    <li><a>Test Page</a></li>
    <li><a>Test Page</a></li>
    <li><a>Test Page</a></li>
    <li><a>Test Page</a></li>
    </ul>
</li>
<li><a>Test Page</a></li>
</ul>
```

I need to append `<div class"arw"></div>` to the `<a>` that is followed by a nested `<ul>` 
so in the example above it would be here

```
<ul class="menu">
<li><a>Test Page</a></li>
<li><a>Test Page</a></li>
<li><a>Test Page<div class="arw"></div></a>
    <ul>
    <li><a>Test Page</a></li>
    <li><a>Test Page</a></li>
    <li><a>Test Page</a></li>
    <li><a>Test Page</a></li>
    </ul>
</li>
<li><a>Test Page</a></li>
</ul>
```

Not sure, the jquery would look something like this:

```
$('.menu li:has(ul)').prev('a').append('<div class="arw"></div>');
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If there will alwyas only be 1 `<a>` tag that is a direct child each `<li>` you could use this

```
$('.menu li:has(ul) > a').append('<div class="arw"></div>');
```

Comment: Wow, was I trying to make that too hard. Worked perfect! Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

```
$('.menu li:has(ul)').find('a:first').append('<div class="arw"></div>');
```

need `.find()` instead.

Or better yet

```
$('.menu li:has(ul) a:first').append('<div class="arw"></div>');
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$('.menu li:has(ul) > a').append('<div class="arw">te</div>');
```

live: http://jsfiddle.net/Q6xEh/